# Google Map API V3 events mousedown, mousemove and mouseup

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to mimic the google earth's desktop version of drawing path in google map. What I have done is when I try to draw a path, I have disabled the default map's draggable event and attached a mousedown event. After the mousedown event, mousemove event is trigger and works accordingly. When the mouse is release event is trapped in mouseup handler where mousemove handler is removed in mouseup event listener. However, this is not working properly after second mousedown and mouseup event.

My code is:

```
var map = 'Already created map object';
var polyOptions = {
                    strokeColor: '#000000',
                    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                    strokeWeight: 2,
                    map: map,
                    idx: 0
                };
var mouseMoveHandler = null;
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mousedown', function(e) {
  mouseMoveHandler = google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mousemove', function(e) {
  // Create a new polyline instance if it does not exists
  if ("undefined" == typeof(GMap._poly[GMap._active_overlay])) {
    GMap._poly[GMap._active_overlay] = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOptions);
  }
  var path = GMap._poly[GMap._active_overlay].getPath();
  path.push(e.latLng);
  }); // End of mousemove lister
  return false;
});

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mouseup', function(e) {
  google.maps.event.removeListener(mouseMoveHandler);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add this to polyOptions:

```
clickable:false
```

without that the polygon will listen for mouse-events and the mouseup-event will fire on the polygon and not on the map.

Answer (score 0):

Example with a tooltip of bootstrap:

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(poly,"mousemove",function(e){

        var _tooltipPolys = $("#tooltipPolys");
        if(_tooltipPolys.length == 0) {
            _tooltipPolys = $(' \
                <div id="tooltipPolys" class="tooltip top" role="tooltip"> \
                    <div class="tooltip-arrow"></div> \
                    <div class="tooltip-inner"></div> \
                </div> \
            ');
            $("body").append(_tooltipPolys);
            $("div.tooltip-inner", _tooltipPolys).text(this.title);
            _tooltipPolys.css({
                "opacity": ".9",
                "position":"absolute"
            });
        }

        var pageX = event.pageX;
        var pageY = event.pageY;
        if (pageX === undefined) {
            pageX = event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
            pageY = event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        }
```